# How to get Search Results to open in browser?

Tags: search-results

I have just set up my Office Online Server for SP2016. Documents are opening in browser from everywhere on the site except for when they are part of the search results.

Central Admin - The open in client setting isn't active.

Doc libs - Set to open in browser

Search preferences - set to open in browser

How can I resolve this please? I want documents to always open in the browser.

All documentation I have found seems to relate to 2010, and the paths/options are different.

Thanks,

Comment: UPDATE:
After the original post yesterday some documents began to open within the browser window - some did not.

I checked the doc library settings (as documents across various) and doc lib settings matched exactly.

This morning I have made edits to the documents that did not open from search results - ran a crawl - and now these documents open in browser.

Overall issue resolved.

Does anyone have an explanation of why this behaviour occurred though?

Thanks